# Add standalone PHP web application to existing site

Tags: php, web, hosting, web-deployment, bitrix

There is a running website (on Bitrix CMS) located on the simplest shared hosting with cPanel. The task is to create a standalone little web application in PHP (for internal use in the company), which, for simplicity, will be available from the same domain, but, what is important, it will not affect the already running site.
On the hosting, in the file manager, there is a `public_html` folder - as I understand these are the site files. I created in `public_html` a subfolder (for example, `webapp`) and added a couple of test files (for example, `test.txt`). The test file is supposed to be available at `site.com/webapp/test.txt`, but nothing is loaded - just a white screen, no error messages.
Trying with text files and simple php-scripts - the same result, just white screen.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .htaccess on site root, it maybe redirecting all routes to index.php of Bitrix CMS.

Alternatively you can follow above answer and create a subdomain.

[Simple tutorial here.](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9190/29/how-to-create-a-subdomain-in-cpanel/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subdomain and point your public_html folder there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Index.php file in the subdirectory, in hosting any folder must have this file which will be executed any time you access that directory with URL.